# No relational fields in response Strapi v4

Tags: javascript, strapi

I have a problem where none of the relational fields are present in the responses after fetching my data. When I look to the schema of one of my schemas with a relation, I see that the relational fields are present in the attributes object. But still I only get the non-relational fields in my response.

**This is one of my schemas**

```
{
  "kind": "collectionType",
  "collectionName": "activities",
  "info": {
    "singularName": "activity",
    "pluralName": "activities",
    "displayName": "activity"
  },
  "options": {
    "draftAndPublish": true
  },
  "pluginOptions": {},
  "attributes": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "date": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "subcategory": {
      "type": "relation",
      "relation": "oneToOne",
      "target": "api::subcategory.subcategory"
    },
    "members": {
      "type": "relation",
      "relation": "manyToMany",
      "target": "api::member.member",
      "inversedBy": "activities"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In `Strapi v4` relations are **not** populated when fetching entries by default.

##### Explaination:

Queries can accept a `populate` parameter to explicitly define which fields to populate, with the following syntax:

`GET /api/:pluralApiId?populate=field1,field2`

###### Example request: Get books and populate relations with the author's name and address

`GET /api/books?populate=author.name,author.address`

For convenience, the * wildcard can be used to populate all first-level relations:

###### Example request: Get all books and populate all their first-level relations

`GET /api/books?populate=*`

###### Example request: Get all books and populate with authors and all their relations

`GET /api/books?populate[author]=*`

***Note:*** *Only first-level relations are populated with `populate=*.` Use the LHS bracket syntax (i.e. `[populate]=*`) to populate deeper:*

###### Example request: Get all relations nested inside a "navigation" component in the "global" single type

`GET /api/global?populate[navigation][populate]=*`

##### Solution:

Change your API url to one of the following and you should be able to see the related fields populated in the response.

`GET /api/activities?populate=subcategory,members`

**OR**

`GET /api/activities?populate=*`

##### Reference:

- [Relations Population](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest/populating-fields.html#relation-media-fields)

Comment: ıt's very clear and good answer. Thanks !

Comment: Important thing when Relation used is of type plugin `Users-Permissions`  
Under admin panel, for Public access to Roles, `find` access has to be granted explicitly. Otherwise the relation does not appear in response even with `populate=*` 
More read the Caution section at - https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest/populating-fields.html#population